# Equivalence of Taylor series and its corresponding function and Axiom for infinite summation

Tags: taylor-expansion, axiom-of-choice, axioms

Given a function $f(x)$ with a taylor series expansion, is it valid to say that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n$$
for all values of x irrespective of whether the taylor series converges for all x? In other words, if we were to sum up all the infinite terms of the taylor series all at once, should we end up with f(x), irrespective of whether the series converges for that particular value of x?

But the action of summing an infinite number of things all at once is similar to the Axiom of Choice in the respect that it is doing an infinite action of taking something from each of infinite number of things.

So the question boils down to the question of whether there already exists, or whether there could exist an axiom which allows us to do that action of infinite summation which I have in mind? Would it be related to the Axiom of Choice? And if it exists should we really end up with the equivalence between the function and its taylor expansion?

Comment: The second half of the question does not make much sense to me, but you might be interested in the fact that the Taylor series in $a=0$ of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k}$$ The function $f(x)$ is perfectly defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$ (moreover, it's $C^\infty$), but the Taylor series diverges for $\lvert x\rvert \ge 1$. We can define an algebraic object, known as [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) and work some algebra in there, but the algebraic operations on that ring are still of finite type.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite summation has a specific definition which does not use the axiom of choice. Just the definition of a sequential limit. It is often beneficial to think about an infinite sum as actually a summation of infinitely many numbers, but in reality it is really just a limit of finite summations.

You don't need the axiom of choice for this, since the sequence of partial sums is well-defined and requires no arbitrary choices; and the definition of a convergent sequence has nothing to do with the axiom of choice.

You also don't need the axiom of choice to show that an analytic function has a Taylor expansion, since the expansion is defined from the function in a very specific way.

Comment: Yes I know that the definition of an infinite sum is the limit of partial sums. So that is one concept of infinite sum. My question is of the whole idea of a (new) different concept of infinite sum where you try and sum all terms together, all at once rather than using any concepts  of limits. It is similar to invoking the Axiom of Choice, in the sense that, when picking a thing from each set, it is not the limit of taking things from a bigger and bigger collection of finite number of sets... but rather the complete action of taking a thing from each set all at once.

Comment: When coming up with a "new concept" you're supposed to suggest some *definition* for it. What is your definition of "a simultaneous summation"? How do you assign a value to a sum? What sort of properties do you expect this new summation to have? Have you proved it does not coincide with the usual definition (which would make it not new at all)? These things are on you, before coming to ask others.

Comment: I am also not sure what the axiom of choice has to do with this. What sets are you choosing from?

Comment: Is it not ok to just ask whether such a concept already exists (or whether there is a reason why it can't exist)? '~' I can't find anything online.

Comment: I was attempting to draw a similarity between the idea of the action of choosing an element from each of an infinite collection of (arbitrary) sets and the idea of the action of "simultaneous summation" because both actions are, in a sense, holistic infinite actions.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can express myself very well so I'll go away and think about it.